# Turbolinks load event doesn't work on page load

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

**I'm having an issue with current default turbolinks recommended load event**:

```js
document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', function() {
  …
});
```

What happens is that this doesn't fire on Safari when page is loaded. Therefore I appended `Turbolinks.dispatch("turbolinks:load");` to `application.js`.

It seemed to work fine. But on Chrome, it did fire automatically, so what it ended up happening is a double-fire of `turbolinks:load` event.

**My first fix was to fire `turbolinks:load` only on non-Chrome browsers.**

But somehow, even on Chrome, some of the views don't trigger `turbolinks:load` automatically. So I ended up having to fire it on specific views too.

**The final solution I found was to use:**

```js
$(document).on('ready turbolinks:load', function() {
  …
});
```

This seems to fix all the issues because it fires on first page load or reload and when I click links. It also fires on Chrome and Safari.

**Is there a better way to handle this?**

Docs say that first version is correct, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

**Am I missing something?**

(note: using jQuery is not a downside for me and I know I could implement that with a couple of `document.addEventListener`)

Comment: How are you loading in Turbolinks? i.e. where are your script tags on the page and are you using `async` on the `<script>`?

Comment: I'm loading the normal Rails way, on assets pipeline.
Then I moved it from body to head and added async on it. Loading all in one js (application.js), so I don't have async issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in the comments, you are loading the Turbolinks with `async`. Turbolinks currently does not work well when loaded asynchronously. So the best advice at the moment is to remove the `async` attribute from the script tag, or use `defer` instead.

### Why?

Turbolinks listens out for the `DOMContentLoaded` event on the first load to then trigger `turbolinks:load`. By loading it asynchronously, it's possible that the script finishes loading/executing *after* the HTML has been parsed and `DOMContentLoaded` fired. In this case, `turbolinks:load` will not be fired.

There is currently a GitHub issue to discuss some possible solutions for the library to implement: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks/issues/281

Comment: Got it, thanks for the reply. So even loading turbolinks inside that application.js (it's all bundled there) is problematic with async.

Should I use defer then?

Otherwise, I would have to move it from the header which defeats the point.

Comment: Yes. Turbolinks depends on the DOMContentLoaded event, which may fire before application.js has loaded and executed. Using `defer` should be okay, as DOMContentLoaded is fired after the scripts have loaded and executed. It's worth noting that even without `defer`, the application.js script will only block on the first load. Subsequent Turbolinks loads will be unaffected. FWIW, I don't think the Turbolinks devs use `defer`. Avoid putting your application.js in the <body>.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
My worry is that placing in the head, without `defer` will cause first time to load to increase, Google / SEO score to decrease, and you know the history.
I will do a test with `defer` then.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't worry _too_ much about placing your script in the <head> unless the file size is huge.

Comment: It's not huge, it's under 300kb, but I think it's a strong recommendation from Google in terms of SEO / page optimization.

Comment: OK. It might be worth performing a performance / SEO audit in Chrome to see how big an impact this is having. FWIW on the main app I work on, we do not defer out script loading, and receive an SEO score of 89, and a performance score of 82, so it may not make a huge difference to how Google ranks your page. However the application.js file is only 81.3 KB (minified/gzipped)

Comment: Will do that. I'm curious if you don't see that recommendation at Google Page Speed tool.

Comment: Yes, it's a recommendation, but given the reasonably high performance/SEO scores, it suggests that it's may not be a huge deal (in my case).

Comment: Oh ok, got it. We are currently in the 90's so I guess that helped.

Comment: I haven't tested one version vs other, but I was having some intermittent issues where sometimes a code inside `$(document).on('ready turbolinks:load', function() {` would be called twice. And now moving `async` to `defer` makes `document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', function() {` work properly and it only fires once, in all cases tested. So definitely, the correct approach here (with `defer` or without anything). Thanks for all the help!