# Rails 6 & turbolinks: 'turbolinks:load' fires before new \<head> scripts are loaded

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I have a Rails 6 project. When a page is loaded using turbolinks the `turbolinks:load` event fires before <head> scripts are merged in and executed. Eventlisteners in those scrips never get executed because they are added after the event has happened.

For example a page with the following in the <head> section of the layout:

```
    = javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload', defer: 'defer'
    = yield :extra_head
```

And this at the top of the page:

```
- content_for :extra_head do
  = javascript_pack_tag 'club_edit'
```

Produces this html:

```
<script src="/packs/js/application-629a480faedfc40e8948.js" data-turbolinks-track="reload" defer="defer"></script>
<script src="/packs/js/club_edit-8d7d256609de3b852df1.js"></script>
```

The club_edit.js file adds a listener to `turbolinks:load` to call a function called `init()`

```
document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', init);
```

When I load the page 'normally' this works as expected and the `init()` function gets called. But if I load it from a turbolinks link, it does its xhr call and the `turbolinks:load` event fires before the listener gets added.

What should I be doing to make sure the `init()` funtion gets called either way?

Comment: On subsequent page loads (i.e., after the first full render), turbolinks loads script files asynchronously and does not wait for all loads to finish before triggering the `load` event. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50120824/turbolinks-load-event-doesnt-work-on-page-load.

Comment: @rmlockerd thanks, I've found lots of similar answers but they all say don't load turbolinks as async. As far as I know I'm not doing so. Surely the whole point of turbolinks:load is a signal that the page has finished loading?

Comment: Did you try explicitly adding `defer: 'defer'` to the `javascript_pack_tag`? The default for external `<script>` tags is immediate execution -- not defer.

Comment: @rmlockerd I have done so now, and updated the question. The result is the same. 'turbolink:load' fires before the club_edit.js script is executed.

Comment: @SteveRawlinson were you ever able to resolve this issue? I'm running into something quite similar.

Comment: @JoeKrump In the end I just removed turbolinks. In my application it made almost no difference to the user experience and considerably improved the developer experience